# currentlyLoading-Event for html5 video-Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, video

I'm looking for a way to create something like a loading animation on a html5 video similar to the Youtube Video display (reference: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5vcCBHVyG50)

I tried it with the canplay-Event but I think I misunderstood the real meaning of this event.

My thought of this event was that enough data has been loaded and buffered so that the video can be played again.

But in my case this event just fires once. At the beginning of the video.

Is there any special Event which will be fired when the video is playable or needs to load more data?

Comment: What exactly are you expecting, i'm not sure to understand?!

Comment: I need an Event with which I can determine if the video is in 'loading'-state so I can visualize it to the user like in my Youtube example

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#event-media-waiting If i'm right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fontAwesome framework. It has got your animation.

Comment: does it have my desired Event on which I can control the animation on?